# Win32::API fail to load win32 dll

Tags: perl, perl-module, activeperl

I am trying to use a Win32 dll in a perl script using Win32::API module. 
For this I have written a perl script like this

```
use Win32::API;
$Win32::API::DEBUG = 1;
$function = Win32::API->new(
  'mydll.dll', 'int func()',
);
$return = $function->Call();
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Win32::API::new: Loading library 'mydll.dll'
FAILED Loading library 'mydll.dll': The specified module could not be found.
Can't call method "Call" on an undefined value at .\test_dll.pl line 6.
```

Although the script and the dll are at the same location, so there is no way it can't find the dll. Also i have tried using the full path.

I am using active perl 5.16 on Windos 7 platform. I have tried this with 5.14 too without any help

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved after adding the other dependent dlls to  the same place as it is .